# Access properties and methods from one class inside another class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to build a class in Objective C that contain serve the web service and database methods for my application. In this class I want to call a web service and grab employee records and then load them into an SQL table for later use in a view.

I got this working when all the code as in the view, but in trying to make this new class (what I am calling GetEmployee) I am running into problems. I do not understand well how to access properties and methods from one class in another.

Here is my GetEmployee Class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "employee.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
#import "FMDatabasePool.h"
#import "FMDatabaseQueue.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"
#import "Utility.h"

@interface GetEmployee : NSObject

{
    NSMutableArray *employees;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *databaseName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *databasePath;

- (void)updateEmployeeData;
- (void)callWebService;
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData;

- (NSMutableArray *) getEmployees;

@end
```

implementation

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define scoularDirectoryURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://XXXXXXXXX/mobile/mobilede.nsf/restServices.xsp/PeopleByName"]

#import "GetEmployee.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"

@implementation GetEmployee


- (id) init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.databaseName = @"employees.db";
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma

- (void)updateEmployeeData{

    //Delete database if it exists and then copy fresh DB
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success;
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];
    if (success) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:self.databasePath error:nil];
    }
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];

    //Call the web service
    [self callWebService];
    [self populateDatabase];
}

- (void) callWebService {
    dispatch_sync(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        scoularDirectoryURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (!jsonArray) {

    } else {

        for (jsonObject in jsonArray){
            employee *thisEmployee  = [employee new];
            thisEmployee.fullName   = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"$13"];
            thisEmployee.ste        = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"state"];
            thisEmployee.city       = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"city"];
            [employees addObject:thisEmployee];
        }
    }
}



-(void) populateDatabase {



////Call the web service and populate the db
//dispatch_sync(kBgQueue, ^{
//    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
//                    scoularDirectoryURL];
//    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
//});

//Populate the db
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
[db open];
for (employee *thisemployee in employees) {
    BOOL success =  [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO employees (fullname,city,state) VALUES (?,?,?);",thisemployee.fullName,thisemployee.city,thisemployee.ste, nil];
    if (success) {} // Only to remove success error
}
[db close];

}




- (NSMutableArray *) getEmployees

{

    //NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
    [db open];
    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM employees"];

    while([results next])
    {
        employee *thisEmployee  = [employee new];
        thisEmployee.fullName   = [results stringForColumn:@"fullname"];
        thisEmployee.city       = [results stringForColumn:@"city"];
        thisEmployee.ste        = [results stringForColumn:@"state"];
        [employees addObject:thisEmployee];
    }

    [db close];

    return employees;

}

@end
```

And here is the MasterViewController

header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "employee.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "FMResultSet.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
#import "Utility.h"

#import "GetEmployee.h"

@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *employees;
    //GetEmployee *ScoularEmployees;
}

@end
```

implementation

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define scoularDirectoryURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://xxxxxxxx/mobile/mobilede.nsf/restServices.xsp/PeopleByName"]

#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "employee.h"
#import "GetEmployee.h"

@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *_objects;
}

@property(strong, nonatomic) GetEmployee *ScoularEmployees;

@end


@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //GetEmployee *ScoularEmployees = [[GetEmployee alloc] init];
    [self.ScoularEmployees init];

    //[self.ScoularEmployees init];

    //_ScoularEmployees = [[GetEmployee alloc] init];
    //[_ScoularEmployees getEmployees];
    //GetEmployee *ScoularEmployees = [[GetEmployee alloc] init];
    //GetEmployee *thisEmployeeData = [[GetEmployee alloc] init];
    //[self.ScoularEmployees updateEmployeeData];
    //[self.ScoularEmployees getEmployees];
    //[ScoularEmployees updateEmployeeData];
    //[ScoularEmployees getEmployees];
}


#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return employees.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *fullName = [[employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"fullName"];
    cell.textLabel.text = fullName;
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        employee *dtlEmployee = [employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:dtlEmployee];
    }
}


- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

    NSError* error;
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    //employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if (!jsonArray) {

    } else {
       //NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc  ]init];
        for (jsonObject in jsonArray){
            employee *thisEmployee  = [employee new];
            thisEmployee.fullName   = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"$13"];
            thisEmployee.ste        = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"state"];
            thisEmployee.city       = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"city"];
            [employees addObject:thisEmployee];
        }
    }

    }


//-(NSMutableArray *) getEmployees

//{

    //NSMutableArray *employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //employees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
//    [db open];
//    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM employees"];
//
//    while([results next])
//    {
//        employee *thisEmployee  = [employee new];
//        thisEmployee.fullName   = [results stringForColumn:@"fullname"];
//        thisEmployee.city       = [results stringForColumn:@"city"];
//        thisEmployee.ste        = [results stringForColumn:@"state"];
//        //[employees addObject:thisEmployee];
//    }
//
//    [db close];
//
//    return employees;
   // return true;
//}



@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I thought it was clear but I can see it is not. In the view class I want to be able to load an NSMutableArray called *employees that comes from the SQLLite database and out them on the screen. I have tried to centralize the code for data access in the GetEmployee class. Everything in that class deals with the data - web service, load the data to the database, and getting the data out of the database as well. So in that Class I have a method "getEmployees" that gets data from the db and loads it into that NSMutableArry. So here is the problem, in the class I cannot get access to the methods or properties in GetEmpployee. That is my question.

Comment: what is your question and what are these code doing here?

Comment: Don't just throw a huge pile of code at us without any mention of what the problem is. Clarify your question and and narrow down the code to just the relevant parts.

Comment: I thought it was clear but I can see it is not.

Comment: You can edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: OK I have edited the question and I hope that it is clearer.

Comment: My advice is to take a step back and understand what you're doing before doing it.  Create two simple classes, one that references the other, understand their interconnect.  This will serve you well in your OO work.

Comment: That is a good idea. I will do that and then come back and clean up my code. I programmed in other OO languages but do not "get" Objective C well yet. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Speaking of "get" don't prefix methods w/"get".  That is reserved for a particular pattern and this isn't it.

Comment: There are no major concept differences between OO programming in Objective-C and OO programming in other languages.  There are plenty of syntax differences, but it's not that hard to deal with.

Comment: @bbum I actually almost never see "get" prefixed methods in Objective-C.  Typically, a "getter" is just the variable name.  So for an instance variable "myInt", you'd use `[myObject myInt];` to get it, and `[myObject setMyInt:42];` to set it... though because most every other language would do `myObject.getMyInt();` and `myObject.setMyInt(42);`, it's still probably best to just not use `get` at all in Objective-C.

Comment: @nhgrif My point exactly.  Well stated in detail. :)

Comment: I do understand getters. Will shy away from using get as a prefix for methods. Also, I understand my problem before; I needed a method with a "+" not a "-". As KevinDTimm suggested, I kind of got bogged down in the details and forgot this simple point. Made a small project and hit upon the problem in 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading through all the code you've posted...

For using a Class method, the syntax is:

```
[ClassName methodName];
[ClassName anotherMethod:withArguments];
```

Methods that are called using this syntax will look like this in the corresponding `.h` file:

```
+(void)methodName;
+(void)anotherMethod:(NSNumber*)number;
```

For using an instance method, the syntax is:

```
ClassName myObj = [[ClassName alloc] init];
[myObj someMethod];
[myObj someOtherMethod:withArguments];
```

Methods that are called using this syntax will look like this in the corresponding `.h` file:

```
-(void)someMethod;
-(void)someOtherMethod:(NSString*)parameter;
```